# data insert in wordpress cutom table not working?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I have created a custom table in WP database ..
But how to insert data in the table.
I have already tried this to do But it not working..

```
 $wpdb->insert(
   'wp_applicants', 
   array('first_name' => $fname, 'last_name' => $lname, 'email' => $others), 
   array('%s', '%s', '%s')
 );
```

Error:
Fatal error: Call to a member function insert() on a non-object in E:\xampp\htdocs\wpjobus\wp-content\themes\wpjobus-child\functions.php on line 22

I have tried this query to insert data in `wp_applicants` table but it's not working.
Any Help??

Comment: What’s in `error_log`? Did you `global $wpdb` before using it?

Comment: Error Log:
Fatal error: Call to a member function insert() on a non-object in E:\xampp\htdocs\wpjobus\wp-content\themes\wpjobus-child\functions.php on line 22

Comment: @KuldeepChoudhary did you also read the second question mudasobwa asked you? "Did you global $wpdb before using it?"

Comment: @RonniSkansing "Did you global $wpdb before using it" i don't know how to do this global...I am just calling $wpdb->insert()

Comment: @mudasobwa thanks globale $wpdb working now....

Comment: You should spend time reading "the manual" before asking questions. Obviously you have not spend time reading http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb and please do not spam the chat room again.

Comment: @RonniSkansing Thanku frnd i will do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare globals:

```
global $wpdb;   // <= mandatory
$wpdb->insert(
   'wp_applicants', 
   array('first_name' => $fname, 'last_name' => $lname, 'email' => $others), 
   array('%s', '%s', '%s')
);
```